# How to enable nicEdit on allTextAreas except one textarea with a given ID?

Tags: javascript, html, nicedit

I have too many textareas on a web site.

I am enabling nicEdit wysiwyg html editor on all text areas with this instanciation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);
</script>
```

I want to disable it on the textarea with the `id="noeditor"`.

Thank you

Comment: is "nicEditors.allTextAreas" an array?

Answer (score 1):

Also have same problem but solved it using jquery. Just put your textarea on a container and replace

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);
```

with this

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    nicEditors.allTextAreas();
    jQuery('.ne-except').each(function(){
        $parent = jQuery(this).parent();
        $parent.children('div').hide();
        $parent.children('textarea').show();
    });
});
```

just add the class `ne-except` to textarea that you want to exclude.

heres my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gozonjoedaimar/9y933f1c/6/

**Update:**
Found out that using this method, textareas inside a form does not post the textareas' value. It uses the value inside the `div.nicEdit-main`. Use the code below to fix this problem.

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    nicEditors.allTextAreas();

    jQuery('.ne-except').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).prev().prev().hide();
        jQuery(this).prev().hide();
        jQuery(this).on('keyup',function(){
            jQuery(this).prev()
                .find('.nicEdit-main')
                .html(jQuery(this).val());
        });
        jQuery(this).show();
    });
});
```

Also updated the code to be independent unlike the previous solution that depends on a div element.